# how to show result dynamically in linux terminal? like 'top' command

Tags: linux, terminal, command

I want to implement a linux command that reads from a changable file and 
 show it in terminal every one second dynamically. how to show result dynamically in linux terminal? like 'top' command? thanks!

Comment: Its already been implemented. Look for `watch` command.

Comment: thank you @Arash , 'watch' can help me. But I want to know how 'top' and 'watch' works, that is how they can flush the output in terminal, maybe I should look at their source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `watch` tool like described in the man (Linux online mans are on man7.org site): http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html

```
   watch runs command repeatedly, displaying its output and errors (the
   first screenfull).  This allows you to watch the program output
   change over time.  By default, command is run every 2 seconds and
   watch will run until interrupted.
```

For example:

```
watch -n 1 tail -n 23 file
```

This will run command `tail -n 23 file` (show last 25 lines of the file `file`) every 1 seconds (option `-n 1` of `watch`). `watch` will run command and print its output, sleep for the amount of seconds and then clear screen with terminal ([ANSI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code)) command sequence. There are several implementations of `watch`, and the simplest is in `busybox` package:  https://git.busybox.net/busybox/tree/procps/watch.c?h=1_17_stable

```
while (1) {
    /* home; clear to the end of screen */
    printf("\033[H""\033[J");
...
    fflush_all();
...
    system(cmd);
    sleep(period);
}
```

There are `\033[H` and `\033[J` sequences to clear screen (and fflush_all is [just](https://git.busybox.net/busybox/commit/procps/watch.c?h=1_17_stable&id=8131eea3dce5fba0dfb78e6083d1730423fad20b) custom busybox variant of [`fflush(stdout)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html)). Linux documents such codes in `console_codes (4)` man page: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html; and `\033` is ESC, `ESC [` is CSI, and `ECMA-48 CSI sequences` section describes CSI `H` and CSI `J` commands:

```
   ECMA-48 CSI sequences

   CSI ( or ESC [ ) is followed by a sequence of parameters .. An empty or
   absent parameter is taken to be 0.  The sequence of parameters may be
   preceded by a single question mark.

   H   CUP       Move cursor to the indicated row, column (origin at 1,1).
   J   ED        Erase display (default: from cursor to end of display).
```